# How do you deal with songs vs. calls when assessing BirdNET detection rates?

Tags: automated-detection, birdsong, birdnet

I am using [BirdNET](https://github.com/kahst/BirdNET-Analyzer) in projects to assess breeding bird acoustic phenology. BirdNET has provided a compelling opportunity to transition away from acoustic indices (which, though useful, provide challenges for easy interpretation) and toward characterizing species-based activity levels instead.

One of the challenges (and opportunities) of BirdNET is that it gives a confidence score output for the species of interest, but it does not classify the detection as a song or call. In avian species, songs and calls are largely believed to have different functions. The song/call issue also presents challenges in verification, particularly if a verifier knows the song well but is less familiar with the various call types a bird may have (I've worked on developing a flexible / generalizable solution to this problem [here](https://github.com/nationalparkservice/NSNSDAcoustics/blob/main/README.md#verify-birdnet-results), but it's not perfect).

In my project, I would prefer to focus more on songs, and am having trouble figuring out how to deal with the songs vs. calls BirdNET detects. I suppose one solution could be to build an additional classifier on top of BirdNET that classifies further into a song or call, and another might be to estimate song vs. call rates throughout the breeding season based on a verified subsample.

How have others dealt with this?

Comment: This is a great question!  I have also wondered about BirdNET's call vs song detection accuracy and rates.  I often have 1000s of predictions but when I review them they are all calls which I am unconvinced are classified correctly.  Ideally, a secondary classifier would be applied? or birdnet would be trained to classify a call vs a song.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend training a model from scratch to specifically recognize the classes you are interested in (rather than training a model to perform a second detection step). This is preferable because if you use two sequential models, your model's performance will be dependant on on high recall (low false-negative rate) of BirdNET.

You could take a "fine tuning" approach by starting with a pre-trained model (on other classes), which can reduce the training data needed to train a good model.

Note that many bird species have several vocalization types, so "song" vs "call" may be a simplification of the diversity of vocalizations. You'll need to decide on a set of classes that you want to identify for any given species.